# Accessing properties of a jQuery object using .load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following funciton:

```
 $('<img/>').attr('src', lrgSrc).load(function(){

       console.log($(this).innnerHeight())
 })
```

The value is always 0, I would like to access the loaded images height. Can someone lend some insight on how to do this please. I feel like this should not be too far off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure it needs to be in the DOM to have a height:

```
var lrgSrc = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/f00/fff.png&text=my+image";

$('<img/>').appendTo('body').attr('src', lrgSrc).load(function(){

       console.log($(this).innerHeight());
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JkWKp/

Also, you had `innnerHeight` instead of `innerHeight`, though I assume that's just a typo in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .height() function ?